# I'm trying to use KivyMD but I'm getting an error

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to make an android app, so I was starting with the menu screen. This is the main file I'm trying to use to create two different screens:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import Snackbar

class FirstWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file('file.kv')


class MyApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        
        return kv
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

The *.kv file that should create a tab with a simple Toolbar

```
WindowManager:
    FirstWindow:
    SecondWindow:


<FirstWindow>:
    name: "first"
    AnchorLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: (0, 0, 0, 1)
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
    MDScreen:
        
        size: root.width, root.height
        orientation: "vertical"
        
        MDNavigationLayout:
            
            ScreenManager:

                MDScreen:

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Title"
                        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'top': 1}
                        md_bg_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.callback(x)]]
                        right_action_items: [["dots-vertical", lambda x: app.callback(x)]]

    





<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Second Screen"
```

I tryied the same code, but replaced the Toolbar with a Label and it worked, but the first code keeps making this error:

```
"""
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\.kivy\logs\kivy_21-12-17_55.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\pythonw.exe"
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 0.104.2, git-bc7d1f5, 2021-06-06 (installed at "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\__init__.py")
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.0.0 - Build 10.18.10.3304'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 2500'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.00 - Build 10.18.10.3304'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\theming.py", line 1126, in __init__
     App.get_running_app().property("theme_cls", True),
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'property'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred. 
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/lao.py", line 19, in <module>
     kv = Builder.load_file('leileilei.kv')
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 306, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 408, in load_string
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 661, in _apply_rule
     child.apply_class_lang_rules(
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 463, in apply_class_lang_rules
     Builder.apply(
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 541, in apply
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 663, in _apply_rule
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 663, in _apply_rule
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 663, in _apply_rule
     self._apply_rule(
   [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 659, in _apply_rule
     child = cls(__no_builder=True)
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\toolbar.py", line 695, in __init__
     self.action_button = MDActionBottomAppBarButton()
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button.py", line 1452, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button.py", line 1123, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\behaviors\elevation.py", line 1145, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button.py", line 1065, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\behaviors\elevation.py", line 847, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button.py", line 891, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\theming.py", line 1134, in __init__
     raise ValueError(
 ValueError: KivyMD: App object must be initialized before loading root widget. See https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/wiki/Modules-Material-App#exceptions
"""
```

What should I do?

Comment: Try moving the `Builder.load_file()` inside the `build()` method.

Comment: Thanks, I just tryied doing this and it worked!